# Retrieving file upload response from Google form using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to retrieve the response data from my Google form so I can upload it to my MySQL database.

So far, I've been able to collect item responses from "Short answer" and "Checkboxes" fields, but I've been having trouble collecting data from a "File upload" field.

More specifically, I want to take whatever the user uploads, convert it to a Blob, and run one of my MySQL prepared statements that uploads that Blob. I haven't been able to do this due to some type-mismatch errors, so I decided to dig a little deeper.

This code...

```
// "files" is an array of objects collected from the "File upload" field
for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(typeof files[i]);
  }
```

... states that the item response is of type "String" rather than a file or Blob.

Does anyone know about any workarounds for this problem? The files that are uploaded by users seem to be going into a folder in my Google Drive, so maybe files can be taken from there and uploaded to my MySQL database? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `The files that are uploaded by users seem to be going into a folder in my Google Drive, so maybe files can be taken from there and uploaded to my MySQL database? ` Yes. Specifically, the string  `file` is the id of the file that was uploaded.